# Is OpenGL processor independent?

Tags: opengl, directx, opencl, gpu

In other word, is there any GPU that does not support OpenGL, and instead support other graphic rendering libraries like DirectX, OpenCl.

Comment: [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) is not a graphic rendering library.

Answer (score 5):

"GPU support of OpenGL" is not uniquely defined. It takes much more than hardware to make OpenGL work. Notably, OS driver infrastructure, and driver itself.

Therefore, it is possible to have a GPU that is capable of all OpenGL features, but have no OpenGL software implementation (either not exists, not installed etc.). Ex.: because of marketing reasons Microsoft does not support OpenGL on XBox. Same thing with Windows: often there is only basic OpenGL available with default Windows graphics drivers. It could be easily fixed by installing vendor driver, but most users don't bother.

And other way around, there are GPUs that are not capable of running some or all of the OpenGL features in hardware. Those features could be implemented in software. Ex.: First Android OS versions had software implementations of OpenGL ES in case phone didn't have dedicated GPU or if GPU was not fully capable of OpenGL ES.

Also, there are platforms that do not support OpenGL or DirectX and use their own APIs. Ex.: Sony use custom API for their Playstations.

Answer (score 3):

At this day and age, no, you'll not find a GPU that won't support *some* version of OpenGL, with the possible exception of some super-specialised chips - but those won't support DirectX either.

Comment: What about the Xbox One?

Comment: @RetoKoradi: If splitting hairs, then what's lacking is a OpenGL *implementation* for the XBox One runtime environment. However the XBox One GPU (Durango) is a derivative of the AMD Radeon HD 7000 family (Southern Islands). There are some differences of course, but either the fglrx or the open source radeon drivers and OpenGL implementations should be fairly easy expanded with support for it.